# Get all the text blocks with more than a certain number lines in a file

Tags: shell

The text blocks are separated by blank lines, like:

```
AAA
BBB

AAA'
BBB'

AAA
BBB
CCC
```

I'd like to get the last text block that has more than 2 lines.
I know I could write a Python script.

How can I do so by using some command line fu?

Comment: I don't know where to start.
I've created my SO account several years ago. Check my profile and you will find out this is the first time I ask a question on SO.
I did help the others. Maybe it's time for me to get some help?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: I think I have misunderstood "*get the last text block*". To simply print all paragraphs with more than 2 lines:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F '\n' 'NF>2' file
```

```
perl -F'\n' -00e 'print if $#F >= 2' file
```

---

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk -v RS= -F '\n' 'NF>2 {rec=$0} END {if (rec!="") print rec}' file
```

`RS` set to a null value enables "paragraph mode". `FS` has been set to `\n` (so that `NF` will be equivalent to the number of lines within each paragraph). The awk program saves the latest record matching the criteria `NF>2` & prints it at the end.

---

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl) using a similar idea (except that perl counts the number of fields differently):

```
perl -F'\n' -l -00e '$rec=$_ if $#F >= 2; END {print $rec if defined $rec}' file
```

---

Depending on the content of the file, it may be faster to read the file backwards, e.g. with `tac`:

```
tac file | perl -F'\n' -l -00e 'if ($#F >= 2) {print $_; exit}' | tac
```